# Cannot remove the last line of a file using python

Tags: python

I have the following that creates several csv files and putting at the end of each a character.
When I open each of the file I notice an extra line I tried to remove it by using

[:-1]

but is not working

```
 newlist = list(chunks(weblinks, 10))
 #PUT EACH LIST INTO FILE
 count = 0
 for nl in newlist:
     if nl:
         #CREATE FILE NUMBERING
         count=count+1
         with open('sktz'+str(count)+'.csv','w',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as f:
             writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
             #PLACE ON LAST ELEMENT A >
             last_elem = nl[-1]
             last_elem[1] = last_elem[1]+'>'
             nl[-1] = last_elem

             for each_elem in nl:
                 if each_elem:
                     writer.writerow(each_elem)
                     #writer.writerow(each_elem[:-1])
```

Comment: You need to remove 1 from `nl` not from each element

Comment: how? can i do it?